# type []int has no field or method length

Tags: go

I have the following code -

```
package "main"

var fibonacciNumbers = []int{0, 1}

func getIthFibo(i int) int {
    if i < fibonacciNumbers.length {
        return fibonacciNumbers[i]
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I get an error at the `if` condition -

```
fibonacciNumbers.length undefined - type []int has no field or method length
```

What I understood was that I created a slice with the elements 0 and 1 - so it should have a length of 2 but I get the above error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The golang way of getting a slices length is to use the `len` function:

```
if i < len(fibonacciNumbers)
```